# Scala transforming a Seq with Future

Tags: scala, future

I have a `Seq` of a tuple that looks like this:

```
Seq[(Future[Iterable[Type1]], Future[Iterator[Type2]])]
```

I want to transform this into the following:

```
Future[Seq([Iterable[Type1], [Iterable[Type2])]
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick

```scala
val a: Seq[(Future[Iterable[Type1]], Future[Iterable[Type2]])] = ...

val b: Future[Seq[(Iterable[Type1], Iterable[Type2])]] = Future.sequence(a.map{
  case (l, r) => l.flatMap(vl => r.map(vr => (vl, vr)))
})
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit simpler than Till Rohrmann's answer. Not tested, but should work.

```
val seq: Seq[(Future[Iterable[Type1]], Future[Iterable[Type2]])] = ...

val seq2 = Future.traverse(seq) { case (f1, f2) => f1.zip(f2) }
```

Or

```
val seq1 = seq.map { case (f1, f2) => f1.zip(f2) } 
// Seq[Future[(Iterable[Type1], Iterable[Type2])]]

val seq2 = Future.sequence(seq1)
// Future[Seq([Iterable[Type1], [Iterable[Type2])]
```

If you actually have `Iterator[Type2]`, as in the question, use `f2.map(_.toIterable)` instead of just `f2`.

Comment: traverse is better, as it won't create intermediate collections. Nice ans.