# Scala Synchronising Asynchronous calls with Future

Tags: scala, future

I have a method that does a couple of database look up and performs some logic.

The `MyType` object that I return from the method is as follows:

```
case class MyResultType(typeId: Long, type1: Seq[Type1], type2: Seq[Type2])
```

The method definition is like this:

```
def myMethod(typeId: Long, timeInterval: Interval) = async {

  // 1. check if I can find an entity in the database for typeId  
  val myTypeOption = await(db.run(findMyTypeById(typeId))) // I'm getting the headOption on this result

  if (myTypeOption.isDefined) {

    val anotherDbLookUp = await(doSomeDBStuff) // Line A

    // the interval gets split and assume that I get a List of thse intervals
    val intervalList = splitInterval(interval)

    // for each of the interval in the intervalList, I do database look up
    val results: Seq[(Future[Seq[Type1], Future[Seq[Type2])] = for {
      interval <- intervalList
    } yield {
      (getType1Entries(interval), getType2Entries(interval))
    }
    // best way to work with the results so that I can return MyResultType 
  }
  else {
    None
  }
}
```

Now the `getType1Entries(interval)` and `getType2Entries(interval)` each returns a `Future` of `Seq(Type1)` and `Seq(Type2)` entries!

My problem now is to get the `Seq(Type1)` and `Seq(Type2)` out of the `Future` and stuff that into the `MyResultType` case class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to this question you asked

[Scala transforming a Seq with Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820332/scala-transforming-a-seq-with-future)

so you get the

```
val results2: Future[Seq([Iterable[Type1], [Iterable[Type2])] = ???
```

and then call await on it and you have no `Futures` at all, you can do what you want.

I hope I understood the question correctly.

Oh and by the way you should map `myTypeOption` instead of checking if it's defined and returning `None` if it's not

```
if (myTypeOption.isDefined) {
  Some(x)
} else {
  None
}
```

can be simply replaced with

```
myTypeOption.map { _ => // ignoring what actually was inside option
  x                     // return whatever you want, without wrapping it in Some
}
```

Comment: What happens if myTypeOption was None? Would the Map do that automatically for me?

Comment: Yes, check sources, line 145 https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L1 This is the whole idea, think of Option as a List with at most one element, if there is something in it all (one) elements will be mapped, otherways it's still empty, nothing to map.

Comment: I edited my original post, so If I do a map on the myTypeOption, then Line A in my original post might fail because of the restriction in the async library!

Comment: Heh, that's right, await is kind of problematic. I usually tend to use map + flatMap and meaningful function names. it could be something like this: `findMyType().flatMap(getResults).map(doTheRest)` where `findMyType` would be function `Unit => Future[Option[MyType]]`, `getResults` would be `Option[MyType] => Future[Option[Results]]` and doTheRest `Option[Results] => Option[MyResultType]` each of those would do the part of processing. You use flatMap if you have function `A => Future[B]` to get `Future[B]` back, using map you would get `Future[Future[B]]`. Anyway async has strong limitations.

Comment: The only reason why I used async is that I want to sequence my database calls without loosing asynchronous behavior. I'm not sure if I could get the same effect with just map and flatMap!

Comment: async is a macro that translates your code into series of maps and flatMaps it was supposed to get things easier (or maybe look more readable). Check sources for map and flatMap for Future class, they basically use onComplete method of Future. So as soon as your firstFuture is done, a function will be called on its result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then this should do the trick.

```scala
def myMethod(typeId: Long, timeInterval: Interval): Option[Seq[MyResultType]] = async {

    // 1. check if I can find an entity in the database for typeId
    val myTypeOption = await(db.run(findMyTypeById(typeId))) // I'm getting the headOption on this result

    if (myTypeOption.isDefined) {

      // the interval gets split and assume that I get a List of thse intervals
      val intervalList = splitInterval(interval)

      // for each of the interval in the intervalList, I do database look up
      val results: Seq[(Future[Seq[Type1]], Future[Seq[Type2]])] = for {
        interval <- intervalList
      } yield {
          (getType1Entries(interval), getType2Entries(interval))
      }
      // best way to work with the results so that I can return MyResultType
      Some(
        await(
          Future.sequence(
            results.map{
              case (l, r) =>
                l.zip(r).map{
                  case (vl, vr) => MyResultType(typeId, vl, vr)
                }
            })))
    }
    else {
      None
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your problem, 1) how to deal with two dependent futures, and 2) how to extract the resulting values.

When dealing with dependent futures, I normally compose them together:

```
val future1 = Future { 10 }
val future2 = Future { 20 }

// results in a new future with type (Int, Int)
val combined = for {
  a <- future1
  b <- future2
} yield (a, b)

// then you can use foreach/map, Await, or onComplete to do
// something when your results are ready..
combined.foreach { ((a, b)) =>
  // do something with the result here
}
```

To extract the results I generally use `Await` if I need to make a synchronous response, use `_.onComplete()` if I need to deal with potential failure, and use `_.foreach()`/`_.map()` for most other circumstances.